# Is there a way to link resource dictionary values to properties in WinUI XAML

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I've written the following in XAML for a slider control and noticed that the `foreground` and `background` properties only set the colour of the `slider track` when not hovering over it, and when not clicking on it.

So I had to write this `Slider.Resources` section to access these resources and override them.

```xml
<Slider 
    x:Name="mySlider"  
    StepFrequency="0.1" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="8" 
    SnapsTo="StepValues" 
    Foreground="#b400ff" 
    Background="#6c4080">
    <Slider.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <!-- Using foreground colour -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver" Color="#b400ff"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPressed" Color="#b400ff"/>

                    <!-- Using background colour -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackFillPointerOver" Color="#6c4080"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackFillPressed" Color="#6c4080"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <!-- Using foreground colour -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver" Color="#b400ff"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPressed" Color="#b400ff"/>
                    
                    <!-- Using background colour -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackFillPointerOver" Color="#6c4080"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackFillPressed" Color="#6c4080"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Slider.Resources>
</Slider>
```

I have other sliders that need different colours for their backgrounds, but being new to XAML and WinUI this feels a bit excessive to define it this way every time. Is there a way to say that all sliders in my project should use the colours for their `foreground` and `background` as the values listed in their Resource Dictionary section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a [custom attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-attached-properties?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) that lets you apply the resources programmatically in a reusable way:

```
public class ThemeService : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThemeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "Theme",
          typeof(SliderTheme),
          typeof(ThemeService),
          new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSet)
        );

    public static void SetTheme(Slider element, SliderTheme value) =>
        element.SetValue(ThemeProperty, value);

    public static SliderTheme GetTheme(Slider element) =>
        (SliderTheme)element.GetValue(ThemeProperty);

    private static void OnSet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider slider = (Slider)d;
        if (e.NewValue is SliderTheme sliderTheme)
        {
            slider.Foreground = sliderTheme.Foreground;
            slider.Background = sliderTheme.Background;

            slider.Resources["SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver"] = sliderTheme.Foreground;
            slider.Resources["SliderTrackValueFillPressed"] = sliderTheme.Foreground;
            slider.Resources["SliderTrackFillPointerOver"] = sliderTheme.Background;
            slider.Resources["SliderTrackFillPressed"] = sliderTheme.Background;
        }
    }
}

public class SliderTheme
{
    public Brush Foreground { get; set; }
    public Brush Background { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<Slider 
    x:Name="mySlider"  
    StepFrequency="0.1" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="8" 
    SnapsTo="StepValues">
    <local:ThemeService.Theme>
        <local:SliderTheme Foreground="#b400ff" Background="#6c4080" />
    </local:ThemeService.Theme>
</Slider>

<Slider 
    x:Name="myOtherSlider"  
    StepFrequency="0.1" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="8" 
    SnapsTo="StepValues">
    <local:ThemeService.Theme>
        <local:SliderTheme Foreground="Red" Background="Yellow" />
    </local:ThemeService.Theme>
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it as `Page` resources:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver"
                    Color="#b400ff" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPressed"
                    Color="#b400ff" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackFillPointerOver"
                    Color="#6c4080" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackFillPressed"
                    Color="#6c4080" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver"
                    Color="#b400ff" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPressed"
                    Color="#b400ff" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackFillPointerOver"
                    Color="#6c4080" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="SliderTrackFillPressed"
                    Color="#6c4080" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Won't this apply to all sliders on that page? The main problem is I have several other sliders that use a different colour theme.

Comment: You could set the `foreground` and `background` separately for several other sliders that use different color themes.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT The problem is slider 1 would have correct hover and click colours, but all the other sliders would have the hover and click colours of the first slider that we defined in page resources